# etoolbox preto command doesn't work when tocloft package is used

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, etoolbox

So I am trying to use:

```
\preto\tableofcontents{
    ...
}
```

to add something before ToC (and same thing for LoF and LoT) in the Class file (i.e. neither adding ... in the real `.tex` file, nor making another command to call ... then `\tableofcontents`)

However, when the package `tocloft` is loaded (for modifying some lengths in ToC), then it seems like the change I made in `\preto` doesn't take effect.

I am wondering if there is a way for `tocloft` to pickup the `\tableofcontents` after I modify it.

Thanks,

Golson

Comment: You will have to delay your patching until "at begin document", tocloft overwrites the standard table of contents

Comment: Do `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}`, so the package will not change the definitions of `\tableofcontents` and `\listof...` commands.

Comment: @daleif Can you add an answer to move this away from the unanswered queue?

Comment: @egreg done   (filler)

Answer (score 2):

Package `tocloft` changes the `\tableofcontents` so your addition probably need to be delayed. A construction like

```
\AtBeginDocument{

}
```

Can be used to delay a reconfigure until after the preamble.

Also note @egregs suggestion of using `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}` which will **not** change the `\tableofcontents` command it self.